# Is it possible to insert text in an TextView?

Tags: android, textview

Appending text in an Android TextView adds the text to the end of the current text. I want to insert some text in a specified location of a TextView without disturbing it's movement while the textview scrolls. Is it possible to insert text? Please help

Comment: I want to insert text while the text scrolls

Answer (score 6):

You can set BufferType of TextView as Editable. It is required only once.

```
textView.setText(textView.getText(), BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

Then you can use:

```
((Editable) textView.getText()).insert(where, text)
```

I believe this way is more efficient if you need to insert text often.

Comment: this is best answer as we don't have reset all text to textview.

Answer (score 2):

I would read the text currently in the TextView, split it at the point I wanted to insert and then put it all together. Like this:

```
String text = myTextView.getText().toString();
String first = text.substring( 0, splitPoint );
String second = text.substring( splitPoint, text.length );

myTextView.setText( first + insertText + second );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String old=textView.getText().toString();

String new= "pre"+old+"after"; // can manipulate using substring also

textView.setText(new);
```

Answer (score 1):

try like below  using string buffer.

```
String string=yourTextView.getText().toString();

StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(string);

    sb.insert(index, "string_to_insert");

string=sb.toString();

yourTextView.setText(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this   and this probably easiest way to do this

```
    String text_view_text=textView.getText().toString();
    StringBuffer sb=new StringBuffer(text_view_text);
    sb.insert(position_to_insert,text_to_insert);
    textView.setText(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

A little off-topic, but if your 'TextView' happens to be EditText...

EditText.getText() actually returns an Editable, not CharSequence or String as one might expect. Editable does have methods to insert and replace text.

```
    Editable e = editText.getText();
    e.insert(pos, text);
    e.replace(start, end, text);
    // etc.
```

The above methods crafting a new string from substrings and then putting it to back to editText is OK, however if your text had any markup it would be lost. Contrary to that editable.insert() / replace() preserves any markup outside of inserted/replaced text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void insertTextAtPoint(String textToAdd, int point) {
  private textBefore = textView.substring(0, point);
  private textAfter = textView.substring(point, textView.getText().toString().length);
  textView.setText(textBefore + textToAdd + textAfter);
}
```